# Microsoft Bot Framework (node.js) - How to pre-populate user input (received message)?

Tags: node.js, chat, botframework, chatbot

I am currently building a chat bot using Microsoft Bot Framework and node.js. 
I would like to find a way of modifying / pre-populate user input/received message.
For example, chat bot asks "What is your age?"
And the user can simply type "25".
For this scenario, instead of just showing 25, I would like to show "My age is 25."
Could anyone please tell me how I can achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is very well documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

```
bot.dialog('nameOfDialog', [
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.number(session, 'What is your age?');
    },
    function (session, results) {
        // user input is stored in results.response
        session.endDialog(`My age is ${results.response}`);
    }
])
```